# PHP String Encoding Error

Tags: php, string, urlencode

I'm trying to get the following code to output an IMG tag with the URL for Google Static Maps API http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Imagesizes embedded in there... the result is that everything except the $address is being output successfully... what am I doing wrong?

```
function event_map_img($echo = true){
    global $post;
    $address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_address', true);
    if($echo): echo '<img src="'.'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='.$address.'&zoom=14&size=700x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:X|'.$address.'&sensor=false" />';
    else:
        return '<img src="'.'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='.$address.'&zoom=14&size=700x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:X|'.$address.'&sensor=false" />';
    endif;
}
```

Comment: What's the function get_post_meta returning?  Add `var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_address', true));`  I have a feeling that it's returning nothing ('' or null)

Comment: sorry guys date_address was supposed to be "_date_address" so it was totally unrelated :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function event_map_img($echo = true) {
    global $post;
    $address = urlencode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_address', true));
    $src = htmlspecialchars('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='.$address.'&zoom=14&size=700x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:X|'.$address.'&sensor=false');
    if ($echo) {
        echo '<img src="'.$src.'" />';
    } else {
        return '<img src="'.$src.'" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem was actually unrelated, sorry for buggin' ya, but you get a gold star anyway since you're right...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `&` separator for `$address` after `blue|label:X|`, it should be like:

```
'&address=' . $address
```